# Excel and float representation

Tags: excel, vba

I cant seem to be able to print the text for exact floating point single representation of a number in excel.

Assume I type the number 3.1 in a cell, the number in single floating point precision is actually 3.099999904632568359375E0 while in double floating point precision is 3.10000000000000008881784197001E0

however, if I set the cell to Number format with 30 decimal places I always see  3.1000000000000000000000000.

I then created a macro (the "memory casting" taken from some other answer here on SO)

```
Type ub4
    b3 As Byte: b2 As Byte: b1 As Byte: b0 As Byte
End Type

Type Float
    r As Single
End Type

Public Sub Test()
    Dim Value As Float
    Dim Text As String
    Dim intval As ub4

    Value.r = CSng(Sheet1.Cells(1, 4).Text)

    Sheet1.Cells(1, 5).Value = Format(Value.r, "#.000000000000000000")

    LSet intval = Value

    Text = "Byte 0: " + Hex(intval.b0) + " Byte 1: " + Hex(intval.b1) + " Byte 2: " + Hex(intval.b2) + " Byte 3: " + Hex(intval.b3)

    Debug.Print Text

End Sub
```

the above macro correctly shows that the memory representation of the single precision floating point is correct (0x40466666)Byte 0: 40 Byte 1: 46 Byte 2: 66 Byte 3: 66

I would like to have my E1 cell to contain 3.099999904632568359375 instead it always end up showing 3.1000000000000000000

Does anyone know how to print the actual floating point value rather than the nice humanly readable rounded one?

EDIT: fixed reference to cell E5 to match the macro which is using E1

Comment: get your google-fu out and research bypassing excel's 15 digit floating point limitation.

Comment: And why would that help me? I dont need more precision I need to print the true floating point digits.

Comment: Do you want the exponent and mantissa of a single cell in **binary** or **hex** ??

Comment: I want to type something in cell 1 for example 3.1 and want the adjacent cell to show me what is the closes single precision floating point representation. E.g. if I type 3.1 in cell D1 (as per the macro above) it will display 3.099999904632568359375 in the E1 cell.

Comment: Excel always round the value to 15 digits before printing, so even if you print more digits you'll only get zeros at the end

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc shouldnt I get at least the first 15 digits of the exact representation (meaning 3.099999904632568)? Or it end up using a double no matter what which is 3.100000000000000 and discard the remainder 08881784197001

Comment: I got your intention now. Excel always uses double precision so if you want to get the single precision value you'll have to write an UDF to cast it down. Writing 3.1 directly will always give you the double precision 3.1

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc that is what i did in the macro above, I am reading the cell content, as a single precision, I am also casting to byte, just to inspect memory and I get the correct binary representation of it. However, when I try to format it to text I still get 3.1, I don't seem to be able to have the string set to 3.099999904632568

Comment: I get 3.0999999046325600000000000000 if I remove your `Format` function. Just assign the value directly `Sheet1.Cells(1, 5).Value = Value.r` and format the cell externally

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc you are right, however this suffer from the same micosoft c library limitation where it doesnt show the full float digits with a printf. Thanks for your help anyway